# C++ code to find and modify/replace a string in .c file

Tags: c++, c, file-handling

My task is to search for a string in .c file and modify it using c++ code. Iam done till searching for the string but modifying it is giving an error. It gives the same error if i copy the contents of c file to a text file and try to modify it. So iam sure something is wrong with my code. Please help as iam a beginner. Thanks in advance.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s1, s2;

  ifstream test("test.csv");

  while (test.eof()==0)      //test.eof() returns 0 if the file end is not reached
  {
    getline(test, s1, ',');     //reads an entire line(row) till ',' to s1

    getline(test, s2, '\n');

    cout << s1 + "= " +s2 << endl;

    fstream fileInput;

    int offset;

    string line;

    string search=s1;

    fileInput.open("IO_CAN_0_User.c");

if(fileInput.is_open()) {

    while(!fileInput.eof()) {

        getline(fileInput, line);

        if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos) {

            cout << "found: " << search << endl;
            string str;
            str=search;
            str.replace(str.begin()+25,str.begin()+31,"=s2  //");
            break;
        }

    }
    //cout << "string not found" << endl;
    fileInput.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file.";


if(test.eof()!=0)
    cout<<"end of file reached"<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `but modifying it is giving an error` You don't think the error might be an important part of the question?

Comment: `while (test.eof()==0)      //test.eof() returns 0 if the file end is not reached` not quite right. it means that the end of file has not yet been reached. The very next read could find the end of file, rendering that read invalid. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Many sourcecode editors support search&replace, often even spanning multiple files. Do you really want to do this yourself?

Comment: Error:Debug assertion failed. Expression: string iterator+offset out of range

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt: yes sir, iam sure i wanna do this myself.

Comment: Here: `string str; search=str;` you create an empty string. In the line after the next line, you try to access `str.begin() + 25`, whoch is clearly illegal for an empty string. (Where do the 25 and the 31 come from?)

Comment: I think the problem here is the replace function i have used. Please let me know how to write to the file at that particular location. I even tried   fileInput << s3 << endl;   it doesnt give any error but the file isnt updated too.

Comment: Thanks M Oehm, there has been a mistake, it is string str; str= search; I changed it, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Look at Matteo's answer: You are using some strange magic numbers here, which would only make sense if your search string were hard-coded, which, by the looks of it, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The error your are facing is not clear, but I can see one big issue, your running `replace` on an empty string.

Your code:

```
string str;
search=str;
str.replace(str.begin()+25,str.begin()+31,"=s2  //");
```

You create `str` (by default initialized as empty string), assign it to `search` (therefore this string gets empty) and then you call `replace` trying to change from char 25 to 31, which are not there since the `str` is empty.

**Update**
Probably you need to fix the replace, but then you cannot expect the file to change: the string you are modifying is in memory, not a piece of your file.

Therefore I would change the code (using yours as much as possible):
 * Adding output file
 * Fixing the replace
 * Saving every line of the input file (*replacing* if need) on the output

```
fileInput.open("IO_CAN_0_User.c");
ofstream  fileOutput;
fileOutput.open("output.c");

if(fileInput.is_open() && fileOutput.is_open() ) {

  while(!fileInput.eof()) {

    getline(fileInput, line);

    if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos) {

        cout << "found: " << search << endl;

        line.replace( offset, offset+search.size(), s2 );
    }

    fileOutput << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Its str=search; I updated it, still the same error. 
 
Error:Debug assertion failed. Expression: string iterator+offset out of range

Comment: Is there any function that i can use instead of s.replace()?

Comment: @NaveenUmashankar: You need to understand your own code better. `str`, the string on which you do the `replace`, goes out of scope immediately. And you determine offset and never use it. Tidy up your `string` definitions; you have only three strings: The current line, the search string and its replacement.

Comment: There was a typo ( offset+s1.size() => offset+search.size()).

Comment: Isn't der any way where i don't have to create a new file altogether? Its quite a large file.

Comment: Yes you could, but it is more complex. 
You can use fseek and fputs (C API)